# InnerJoin query on Django QuerySet

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have these data models in django:

```
class User(models.Model):
     type = models.CharField()

class Tmp1(models.Model):
     var1 = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Tmp2(models.Model):
     var2 = models.ForeignKey(Tmp1)

class Tmp3(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     var3 = models.ForeignKey(Tmp2)
```

I want to have a `Tmp3` queryset which selects instances of `Tmp3` which `Tmp3.var3.var2.var1.id` equals `Tmp3.user.id.`

I know how I should do it with InnerJoin in PostgreSQL but I don't know how to do it with Django queryset.

Comment: One of the features of django is that it is db agnostic. This is not a particularly complicated query for an ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want to get `Tmp3` objects in which their `user` attribute matches the related user in the `Tmp1` table (for the current `Tmp3` object) - it sounds like you can make use of [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#query-expressions)

```
from django.db.models import F
Tmp3.objects.filter(var3__var2__var1=F('user'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
object_q = 1
tmp3_pk = Tmp3.objects.get(pk=object_q).user.pk
queryset = Tmp3.objects(var3__var2__var1__pk=tmp3_pk)
```

The `__` (double underscore) will refer to an attribute of related model.

You can also refer to objects directly:

```
object_q = 1
tmp3_user = Tmp3.objects.get(pk=object_q).user
queryset = Tmp3.objects(var3__var2__var1=tmp3_user)
```

See the full details of performing queries across related objects here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects

Comment: @pooria have you tried this solution before you down voted it? Do you understand what question you're asking? Do you understand that queries are only performed on instantiated data?

Comment: down voting a post needs more than 125 reputation. I have only 76 :). your answer is irrelevant and maybe this is why somebody has down voted it.

Comment: Also, I just tried this query and it does work. Though there are problems with your models (in the django sense).